# How do I fix pip on replit?

Tags: python, pip, replit

Whenever I run a command related to pip, or pip itself, it just returns an exception and it doesn't install anything

Here's the exception info:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main import main
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
      from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
      from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 27, in <module>
      from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir, enum
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 38, in <module>
      from pip._vendor.tenacity import retry, stop_after_delay, wait_fixed
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/tenacity/__init__.py", line 522, in <module>
      from pip._vendor.tenacity._asyncio import AsyncRetrying
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/tenacity/_asyncio.py", line 19, in <module>
      from asyncio import sleep
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
      from .base_events import *
    File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncio/base_events.py", line 296
      future = tasks.async(future, loop=self)
```

I was running pip commands to install libraries on replit (because upm doesn't work well), but after uninstalling discord.py, it doesn't seem to work properly anymore

Comment: What is the library that you are trying to install?

Comment: If pip isn't working, try reinstalling python and adding it to the `PATH` as well.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience it is much better to use the pip module instead of the executable.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip # upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install replit        # install the desired module
```